# Passing argument from one function to another

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if this way of passing an argument from one function to another (let's say from f1 to f2):

```
f1 = function(arg){
    f2(arg);
}

f2 = function(arg){
    //doing sth with passed argument
}
```

Is wrong? Or is it better/safer to always use the .apply() method, even if we're not passing an array?
To clarify- argument is passed only to f1, and only from f1 f2 is called.

Comment: what does `.apply()` have to do with passing an array?

Comment: Nothing, but every example I've seen involved passing a number of arguments and .apply(), so I was curious if there's something wrong with the first scenario when we're dealing with only one argument. A beginner here :) But I got my answer now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not wrong.

Passing parameters through functions is one of the fundamental aspects of JavaScript as a language. It helps you take a complex application and break it down into manageable chunks for both clarity and maintainability.

`.apply` is useful when you want to call a function with a specific scope ( that's why the first parameter is `this` ) and it takes an array or array-like secondary parameter for arguments to be used within the function. The fact that it's an array/array-like makes no difference at all to you as a programmer or to the function that you're calling. There's nothing special about it, it's just the format that `apply` expects.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong about that at all. This happens all the time.

The only reason you should use `apply()` is if you need what it does, like changing the context (value of `this`) or passing an array as individual arguments. You aren't doing anything like that here, so there is absolutely no reason to make more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare an argument in JavaScript it's treated just like a variable, and you can use it like any other variable: reassign values, pass it to another function, etc. `.apply(this, arguments)` is also possible, but it's not *necessary* unless you need to set the `this` of the called function or to pass an arbitrary number of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The apply() method takes arguments as an array.

The apply() method is very handy if you want to use an array instead of an argument list.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Functions</h2>

<p>In this example the fullName method of person is <b>applied</b> on person1:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var person = {
    fullName: function(city, country) {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + "," + city + "," + country;
    }
}
var person1 = {
    firstName:"John",
    lastName: "Doe",
}
var x = person.fullName.apply(person1, ["Oslo", "Norway"]); 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x; 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

While if you use two function and call One in another:

```
function function_one() { function_two(); } 

function function_two() { 
 //enter code here 
}
```

Function parameters are the names listed in the function definition.

Function arguments are the real values passed to (and received by) the function.

Parameter Rules

JavaScript function definitions do not specify data types for parameters.

JavaScript functions do not perform type checking on the passed arguments.

JavaScript functions do not check the number of arguments received.

Parameter Defaults

If a function is called with missing arguments(less than declared), the missing values are set to: undefined

more information JavaScript you can read this link
https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript